# Is it a bad practice to return different properties for each entity implementation?

Tags: json, rest

I'm building a REST API and I have an entity `Contact` (interface) with two implementations:

```
interface Contact {
    val id: String
    val email: String
}

class IndividualContact(
    override val id: String,
    override val email: String
    val name: String,
    val lastName: String) : Contact

class CompanyContact(
    override val id: String,
    override val email: String
    val tradeName: String) : Contact
```

I have an endpoint *"GET /contacts"* that returns all the contacts, individuals and companies. So, the response looks like this:

```
[
    {"id": "1", "name": "John","lastName": "Doe", "email": "john@mail.com"},
    {"id": "2", "tradeName": "ACompany", "email": "hello@acompany.com"}
]
```

As you see, properties differs. Is this a bad practice? Is it a bad practice even if I include a discriminator property `type` in each item?

Comment: I would expect get company contacts & individual contacts to be separate endpoints, like /contacts/companies and /contacts/individuals or other meaningful name

Comment: Agree with @Héctor, but it also looks like you are trying to use inheritance. If so then your parent class should have all the similarities and the children classes should have all the same stuff as the parents **plus** some. Typically in inheritance there is no removal of attributes. This will ensure that the typical attributes are there and the same for everyone to use, but that any extra will also be available.

Comment: @Rohlex32 Of course, both implementations have id and email. They are the common properties. No removal of attributes here.

Comment: Then with that in mind then I would say that it is _not_ bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a bad practice? Is it a bad practice even if I include a discriminator property type in each item?

I wouldn't consider it a bad practice, necessarily - but it may be incomplete.

The piece that seems to be missing is anything that looks like a stable *schema*; what assumptions are consumers expected to make about data that is present, data that is missing, and so on.

For instance, in this case we might have schema that look something like

```
Required: { id: integer, email: string}
Optional-Extension-1 : { name: string, lastName string }
Optional-Extension-2 : { tradeName: string }
```

Expressed *this* way, you have a homogeneous set of properties.  It just happens in your example that the first answer has the `Required` and `Optional-Extension-1` parts, where the second entry has the `Required` and `Optional-Extension-2` parts.

So long as the clients have a clear understanding that they must-ignore/must-forward the optional parts that they don't understand, and have some sense for what standard thing to do if a part they are expecting is missing, you can add (documented) extensions to your hearts content.

[Versioning in Event Sourced Systems](https://leanpub.com/esversioning), by Greg Young, is a good starting point.  You can also find good hints in the documentation for many of the standard message formats (Protocol Buffers, Avro, etc.)

The very basic rules are: you can't add new required fields to an existing message schema, and you can't change the meaning of fields that are defined.  (If you need to do either of those, you are defining a new message schema altogether).